# How can I use request as a proxy to inject a header to responses

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-request

I have created a proxy to run locally so I have control over inbound requests.

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

var app = express();
var apiUrl = 'http://my-service/resource';
var port = parseInt(process.env.APP_PORT || '23048');
var appName = 'forwarding-proxy';

app.use('*', function(req, res) {
    var x = request(apiUrl);
    req.pipe(x);
    x.pipe(res);
});

app.listen(port);

console.log('Started at http://localhost:' + port + '/' + appName + '/');
```

How can I modify this to inject the following header to responses?

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-total-count, X-page-count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var x = request(apiUrl);
req.pipe(x).on('response', function(res) {
    res.headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = "X-total-count, X-page-count ";
}).pipe(res);
```

With some more explanation on your specific issue, I may be able to assist you in better alternatives.

Comment: The inbound response is missing the header, and I would like to add it manually in the proxy.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you want, but could you please try the new code !